# Which country to apply schengen visa when staying for equal number of days in 2 countries and port of entry is 3rd country?

Tags: france, schengen-visas, applications, switzerland

I will be travelling to France and Switzerland with Family. Stay in both France and Switzerland is 5 days. As I am travelling through Lufthansa my port of entry and exit is Germany but I am not staying in Germany other than transit. 
In this case, should I be applying for Visa through germany?

Comment: Is there a recognizable main purpose to the trip in any one country?

Comment: Visit is purely from tourism perspective with 5 days in both countries and want to see and visit tourist places of both countries.

Answer (score -2):

The rules telling you where to apply exist to spread the workload between the different countries participating in Schengen.

You must apply to the country that is your main destination. The main destination is the country you spend most time in. If you plan spending an equal amount of time in two countries you need to apply to the first of the two.

So if you got to France first you need to apply to a French consulate.

Comment: This would be a reasonable rule, but isn't [what the Visa Code actually says](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32009R0810). It says: **if no main destination can be determined, the Member State whose external border the applicant intends to cross in order to enter the territory of the Member States**. It is possible that the people who drafted the code imagined this would usually be one of the countries with an equally long stay, but it is hard to interpret the actual text to mean that.